# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know much JS. So this is hard for me to figure out. I'm getting this error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

```
    <script>

    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');

    var btn = document.getElementById("modalbtn");

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    btn.onclick = function() {modal.style.display = "block";}


    span.onclick = function() {modal.style.display = "none";}


    window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {modal.style.display = "none";}
}

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It's because the thing I'm calling isn't present on the page I'm getting the error.

Thanks